# How do I convert Dragonmech to D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, conversion, d20-system, dragonmech

So I was looking at Dragonmech, and it seems really cool, and is something I would want to use to DM with my group of friends. My only problem is that none of us know how to play DnD 3.5, and we're all pretty content with 5e. So how would I convert Dragonmech to D&D 5e?

Answer (score 1):

If you're really interested in doing this, there's a conversion guide available from the playdnd.com website.  The document is located at: http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DnD_Conversions.pdf

Take special care with some of the dragonmech spells, since they got crazy.

Comment: Your answer would be much more helpful if it went through the methodology of the conversion.

Comment: @IlyaDonskikh, I didn't include that in the answer because I couldn't come up with a way to answer without regurgitating the entire document, and I don't think long step-by-steps are considered 'good' answers either (until we get Documentation?).  Granted, i was poking around and found http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84081/how-can-i-convert-enemies-from-dd-3-5e-to-5e?rq=1 that gives a similar answer with a quote from the document, though I suppose I could include that same block for consistency.

Comment: What I meant by methodology is *how* to go about it, not the exact step - by  - step conversion, although a summary of that definitely would help, and not be considered 'regurgitating' the document you linked. In fact, it'd be the same as citing and summarising portions of it, as an answer should be grounded in evidence.

Comment: Even if you don't summarize much of the process, it sounds like you've got *experience* with it: it'd be good to share your *expertise*. Was it fun using this? More trouble than you thought worth? Which particular spells gave you trouble? &c.